# How to select sqlite result from multiple tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to select result in sqlite from multiple tables with multiple foreign keys, I tried `JOIN` but it did not work that well; for example :

a table for `STUDENT` :

```
 CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
 STUDENT_NAME    TEXT        NOT NULL,
 STUDENT_NUMBER  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
 STUDENT_ADDRESS TEXT        NOT NULL
 );
```

and a table for `EXAMS` :

```
 CREATE TABLE EXAMS(
 EXAM_CODE      INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
 EXAM_SUBJECT   TEXT        NOT NULL,
 EXAM_LOCATION  TEXT        NOT NULL
 );
```

and a table called `WROTE_EXAM` to get the information for students who wrote a specific exam

```
 CREATE TABLE WROTE_EXAM (
 STUDENT_NUMBER  INTEGER     NOT NULL,
 EXAM_CODE       INTEGER     NOT NULL,
 DATE            DATE        NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(STUDENT_NUMBER) REFERENCES STUDENT(STUDENT_NUMBER),
 FOREIGN KEY(EXAM_CODE) REFERENCES EXAMS(EXAM_CODE));
```

this is a sample data inserted into tables :

```
STUDENT_NAME : John
STUDENT_NUMBER: 123456789
STUDENT_ADDRESS : 10th street
EXAM_CODE: 123
EXAM_SUBJECT: One Subject
EXAM_LOCATION: Class
```

now, I want to : 
a) output student names, exam codes and student location, who wrote the exam 
b)  output exam code, exam subject and exam location for student with ID : 123456789

thanks

Comment: What JOINs did you try?

Comment: @muistooshort I did `SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT_NAME,EXAM_CODE,STUDENT_LOCATION FROM WROTE_EXAM,STUDENT JOIN EXAMS,STUDENTS` not sure how to join 3 tables together and get this information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When joining tables you almost always want to include an explicit join condition. The SQLite [syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#join-op) may be helpful:

[image: Join Op]
[image: Join Constraint]

So the SQL from your comment should look more like this:

```
select student.student_name, exams.exam_code, ...
from student
join wrote_exam using (student_number)
join exams using (exam_code)
where ...
```

or you could use JOIN...ON:

```
select student.student_name, exams.exam_code, ...
from student
join wrote_exam on student.student_number = wrote_exam.student_number
join exams on exams.exam_code = wrote_exam.exam_code
where ...
```

Then add `where` conditions to filter the results as needed.

Note that I've also added some table qualifiers to the columns in your SELECT clause, those are needed to uniquely specify which `exam_code` you're interested in and since one column needs to be qualified, I did them all for consistency; in real life I'd prefix them all to make things nice and explicit.

Also, I don't see a `student_location` anywhere, perhaps you mean `student.student_address` or `exams.exam_location`.